# Xamarin Android Layout file treated as int?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

Now I can't seem to find any help for this on the internet so I'm doing something wrong obviously, or I'm typing the wrong thing into google. I'm using Xamarin to creating an Android app and I'm trying to use Fragments within the app.

In the fragment file I'm trying to set the LayoutInflater in the **OnCreateView** method. However, when I state the layout file "**Resource.Layout.Profile**" it's coming through as an *int* instead of a *layout inflater*? I've tried casting it as a layout inflater and it causes an exception saying it can't be cast to that.

Code:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(Resource.Layout.Profile, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Now I'm not massively experienced at Native Android development (only what I've done at University) and this is my first Xamarin Android app so I think I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a Ressource.Layout.Profile. That's not a Layout inflater.
The layout inflater is the variable you receive under the name inflater.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: So when I read the Android guide to Fragments they set the layout where it says inflater like I had it, if not that way where do I call **OnCreateView**?

Guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: The same practice is also used in a Xamarin guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/

Comment: You don't call onCreateView, it's called for you by the system automaticly. Then they hand you an inflater to "inflate" your XML file. In your code here, you are doing nothing. just calling super and passing the same arguments is the same as not implementing the method, it's android studio default behavior, but it is not what you must do. This method MUST return the view you want to display in your fragment. take a look here: http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/android-example-oncreateview-method-fragment-class

Comment: read your link carrefully. the xamarin.com link returns return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Example_Fragment, container, false); Do you see the difference with what you do : return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); ???

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was the fact that I had it re-calling OnCreateView still whereas in the guide they changed it to **inflater.Inflate**.

I had this: **return base.OnCreateView(Resource.Layout.Profile, container, savedInstanceState);**

But needed this: return **inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Profile, container, false);**